# When I send a numpy array to a givens parameter in a theano function, why do I get this Theano TypeError

Tags: python, theano

I am new to theano, and am still struggling with the"pseudo code" style of theano on the one hand and strict type checking on the other. I am more of a C programmer and a python programmer. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong in this example code which uses mean square error between predicted y points and training y points for x values, to get the optimal slope and intercept of a linear fit?

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from collections import OrderedDict

class LinearModel:
    def __init__(self,num_points):
        self.m = theano.shared(value=0.1,name='m')
        self.b = theano.shared(value=1, name='b')
        self.params = [self.m, self.b]

        def step(x_t):
            y_t = self.m * x_t + self.b
            return y_t

        self.x = T.matrix('x',dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.y, _ = theano.scan(
                        fn=step,
                        sequences=self.x,
                    ) 

        self.loss = lambda y_train: self.mse(y_train)

    def mse(self, y_train):
        return T.mean((self.y - y_train) ** 2)

    def fit(self,x, y, learning_rate=0.01, num_iter=100):
        trainset_x = theano.tensor._shared(x.astype(np.dtype(np.float32)),borrow=True)
        trainset_y = theano.tensor._shared(y.astype(np.dtype(np.float32)),borrow=True)
        n_train = trainset_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]

        cost = self.loss(trainset_y)
        gparams = T.grad(cost,self.params)

        l_r = T.scalar('l_r', dtype=theano.config.floatX)

        updates = OrderedDict()
        for param,gparam in zip(self.params,gparams):
            updates[param] = param - l_r * gparam

        self.train_model = theano.function(  inputs=[l_r],
                                        outputs=[cost,self.y],
                                        updates=updates,
                                        givens={
                                              self.x: trainset_x,
                                            }
                                        )

        epoch = 0
        while epoch < num_iter:
            cost, _ = self.train_model(learning_rate)
            m = self.m.get_value()
            b = self.b.get_value()
            print "epoch: ",epoch," cost: ",cost," m: ",m," b: ",b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lin = LinearModel(10)
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)
    lin.fit(x,y,learning_rate=0.01,num_iter=100)
```

---

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "~/EclipseWorkspace/MemoryNetworkQA.Theano/linear_regression.py", line
>   70, in 
>       lin.fit(x,y,learning_rate=0.01,num_iter=100)   File "~/EclipseWorkspace/MemoryNetworkQA.Theano/linear_regression.py", line
>   54, in fit
>       self.x: trainset_x,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function.py",
>   line 266, in function
>       profile=profile)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line
>   489, in pfunc
>       no_default_updates=no_default_updates)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line
>   217, in rebuild_collect_shared
>       raise TypeError(err_msg, err_sug)
>
> TypeError: ('An update must have the same type as the original shared
>   variable (shared_var=b, shared_var.type=TensorType(int64, scalar),
>   update_val=Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}.0,
>   update_val.type=TensorType(float64, scalar)).', 'If the difference is
>   related to the broadcast pattern, you can call the
>   tensor.unbroadcast(var, axis_to_unbroadcast[, ...]) function to remove
>   broadcastable dimensions.')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't execute until the following problems have been addressed.

1. The error reported in the question is due to the type of `self.b` not matching the type of the update for `self.b`. `self.b` has no type specified so one has been inferred. The initial value is a Python integer so the inferred type is an `int64`. The update is a `floatX` because the learning rate is a `floatX`. You can't update an `int64` with a `floatX`. The solution is to make the initial value a Python float resulting in an inferred `floatX` type. Change `self.b = theano.shared(value=1, name='b')` to `self.b = theano.shared(value=1., name='b')` (note the decimal point after the `1`).
2. The next problem is that `self.x` is defined as a matrix but the value passed in the function call in the last line is a vector. A solution is to reshape `x` into a matrix, e.g. change `x = np.arange(10)` to `x = np.arange(10).reshape(1,10)`.
3. The trainset shared variables have type `float32` but this conflicts with other areas of the code that is working with `floatX`. If your `floatX=float32` then there should be no problem but it would be safer to simply use `floatX` to maintain the same float type throughout. Change `trainset_x = theano.tensor._shared(x.astype(np.dtype(np.float32)),borrow=True)` to `trainset_x = theano.tensor._shared(x.astype(theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)` and similarly for `trainset_y`.
4. The number of epochs is not currently having any effect because `epoch` is not being incremented. Change `while epoch < num_iter:` to `for epoch in xrange(num_iter):` and remove `epoch = 0`.

In addition,

- The parameters look like they're not updating but this is a false view. The iterations pass quickly and never stop because of problem 4 above and the learning rate is large enough to make the model converge very quickly. Try changing the learning rate to something much smaller, e.g. 0.0001, and look at the output for only the first 100 epochs.
- I'd recommend avoiding the use of `theano.tensor._shared` unless you really do need to force the shared variable to be allocated on the CPU when `device=gpu`. The preferred method is `theano.shared`.
- The `n_train` variable isn't used anywhere.
- You're using `givens` inconsistently. I'd recommend using it for both `x` and `y`, or for neither. Take a look at the [logistic regression tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) for more pointers on this.
- The Theano function is being recompiled on every call to `fit` but you'd be better off compiling it only once and reusing it on each `fit`.
- This model can be implemented without using `scan`. In general, `scan` is often only needed when the output of a step is a function of the output from an earlier step. `scan` is also generally much slower than alternatives and should be avoided when possible. You can remove `scan` by using `self.y = self.m * self.x + self.b` instead.
- If you do use scan, it's good practice to enable strict mode, via `strict=True` in the `scan` call.
- It's good practice to explicitly provide types for all shared variables. You do this for `trainset_x` and `trainset_y` but not for `self.m` and `self.b`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I agree about the self.b. That solved the previous problem. I am looking into your other comments to see if it solves my problem that the updates are not really happening.

Comment: I've added an additional explanation for why it looks like the parameters are not changing.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your comments on the code! Yes, after correcting, its working and I understand what is happening now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that the problem was really in the self.b. After initializing it with an explicit float, the type error goes away.

But the slope and intercepts (self.m and self.b) which are still theano shared variables and are being passed in through updates, are not really getting updated. If anyone can tell me why, it will be a great help. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from collections import OrderedDict

class LinearModel:
    def __init__(self,num_points):
        self.m = theano.shared(value=0.1,name='m')
        self.b = theano.shared(value=1.0, name='b')
        self.params = [self.m, self.b]

        def step(x_t):
            y_t = self.m * x_t + self.b
            return y_t

        #self.x = T.matrix('x',dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        #self.x = T.dmatrix('x')
        self.x = T.vector('x',dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.y, _ = theano.scan(
                        fn=step,
                        sequences=self.x,
                    ) 

        self.loss = lambda y_train: self.mse(y_train)

    def mse(self, y_train):
        return T.mean((self.y - y_train) ** 2)

    def fit(self,x, y, learning_rate=0.01, num_iter=100):
        trainset_x = theano.tensor._shared(x.astype(np.dtype(np.float32)),borrow=True)
        trainset_y = theano.tensor._shared(y.astype(np.dtype(np.float32)),borrow=True)
        n_train = trainset_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]

        cost = self.loss(trainset_y)
        gparams = T.grad(cost,self.params)

        l_r = T.scalar('l_r', dtype=theano.config.floatX)

        updates = OrderedDict()
        for param,gparam in zip(self.params,gparams):
            updates[param] = param - l_r * gparam

        self.train_model = theano.function(  inputs=[l_r],
                                        outputs=[cost,self.y],
                                        updates=updates,
                                        givens={
                                              self.x: trainset_x,
                                            }
                                        )


        epoch = 0
        while epoch < num_iter:
            cost, _ = self.train_model(learning_rate)
            m = self.m.get_value()
            b = self.b.get_value()
            print "epoch: ",epoch," cost: ",cost," m: ",m," b: ",b
            epoch += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lin = LinearModel(10)
    x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0])
    y = np.random.rand(10)
    lin.fit(x,y,learning_rate=0.01,num_iter=100)
```

Comment: See my updated answer for information on why the parameters look like they're not updating.

Comment: Yes, after correcting, I can see its updating and I understand what is happening now! Thanks a lot